# How do you connect a MS botframework bot to Skype for Business

Tags: botframework, skype-for-business

I published a bot built using the bot framework but I can't figure out how you'd connect it to Skype for Business on an internal Corporate network.

Does any know what the process is?

----- Ed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Skype for Business is not yet supported.

Comment: Not sure I understand you comment.  No link was provided in the answer.

Comment: The FAQ says Skype is supported.  Maybe in April it wasn't, but it says it is now.

Comment: Skype For Business (formerly Lync) and Skype are different products.  Skype is the consumer version.  Skype For Business is the enterprise solution.

Comment: I know MS Bot Framework is not yet supported for Skype for Business, but is it upcoming ? If not, then is there any easy workaround to support this ?

Answer (score 1):

I think he means is there a guide to building a bot for "Skype For Business". I'm looking to build one for our company as well.

Answer (score 1):

FYI - Skype for Business was announced as a new channel today on Build 2017 :)

Answer (score 1):

right now, SFB is already supported by Bot Framework. Please, go to the portal https://dev.botframework.com, select your bot, and look into the channels link. You'll see how to enable & configure your bot to be used within SFB.

Please, feel free to ask me if you have questions

Comment: Is there a way to add the bot in SFB for testing purpose like we do with skype or teams?

Comment: Hello, I'm afraid it's not so easy... you should access SFB installation with a tenant, and it's almost sure you aren't within your organization. What I did to solve it, was to create an evaluation instance of Office 365, so I could work and test my bot during the evaluation period (1 month). I don't know if there is another way to test the bot.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully deployed my Bot to SFB referring the below link
[Bot deployment to Skype For Business](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/skype-for-business-bot-framework/docs/overview#feature-support)

But now, things are little changes, below are the high level steps

- Deploy your bot to Azure App service Plan
- integrate with SFB channel, azure portal will give you channel specific details. Click on Edit link to get the details on how to integrate your bot.
  [Azure Portal Bot Channels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHL1U.png)
  Click on "Learn How"
  [Learn how to integrate Bot to SFB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgZGl.png)
- Once Channel is added, you would need a tenant administrator who can do powershell  scripting.
- What you need to provide is the default URL of your bot , you can give WebChat URL (which is your default channel), Microsoft Application ID etc.
- And then give a nice name to your bot.
- After the integration your bot will be active after 24 hours.